# rockly linux /dev/mapper/rl-root 100% full

Tags: linux, rhel, disk-usage

I am experiencing random glitches throughout the day were some php script say no enough space.. I have 1 TB drive and about 200 GB used so I have plenty of space. I have checked logs and directories all seems to be okay. What can I do to make sure that this does not keep happening?

```
[(01:44 PM)] [(~)] $ df -h
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs              63G     0   63G   0% /dev
tmpfs                 63G  120K   63G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 63G  106M   63G   1% /run
tmpfs                 63G     0   63G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/rl-root   70G   70G  668M 100% /
/dev/mapper/rl-home  856G  121G  736G  15% /home
/dev/nvme0n1p2      1014M  294M  721M  29% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1       599M  5.8M  594M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                 13G     0   13G   0% /run/user/0
```

then when i test a php script this is what I get

```
[(12:14 PM)] [(/home/virtual/sites/)] $ php test.php
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Error writing file '/tmp/MLfd=71' (OS errno 28 - No space left on device)
```

here's some sizes of directories with the most data

```
[(01:58 PM)] [(/)] $ du -sh * | sort -h
4.0K    tmp
108K    root
120K    dev
312K    opt
27M     etc
106M    run
260M    boot
2.8G    usr
66G     var
114G    home

[(01:59 PM)] [(/var)] $ du -sh * | sort -h
4.0K    tmp
32K     spool
44K     www
68K     named
4.9M    cache
2.9G    log
64G     lib

[(01:59 PM)] [(/var/lib)] $ du -sh * | sort -h
4.0K    chrony
4.0K    logrotate
4.0K    unbound
12K     NetworkManager
12K     setroubleshoot
36K     alternatives
148K    systemd
592K    php
676K    shorewall
1.2M    pear
5.6M    dnf
27M     selinux
30M     mlocate
33M     sss
240M    rpm
63G     mysql
```

Comment: your mysql instance use 63G in `/` try moving it to `/home`

Comment: stop mysql then mv /var/lib/mysql /home/mysql then edit path in my.cnf.. anything else or that should do it?

Comment: I would copy rather than move, edit my.cnf and see if it starts.